# How to use the Zoom Meeting Web SDK in an Ionic app using Android WebView?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, zoom-sdk

I'm working on an Ionic app that needs to integrate with the Zoom Meeting SDK. I'm aware that the Ionic Zoom Meeting SDK plugin is no longer officially supported, but I found a workaround that involves using the Zoom Web SDK method to build an Android app using Android WebView.

https://devsupport.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/13662982186509

I have managed to build the Angular part of the app in Ionic, and it works fine when I run it in a web browser. However, when I try to run the app on an Android device, nothing happens when I click on the Zoom meeting link.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to tweak the angular code to make the Ionic Zoom Meeting SDK plugin work in an Android app using Android WebView? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!